# stage.update() is undefined using PreloaderJS

Tags: javascript

I just started using createjs and I have this noob issue. I can't make an image show after it was preloaded using PreloaderJS. My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var queue, bg;
        var stage;
        function init(){
            stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
            queue=new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
            queue.on("complete", handleComplete, this);
            queue.loadFile({id:"background", src:"http://localhost/img/mainGameBG.png"});
            queue.load();

        }

        function handleComplete(event){
            bg = queue.getResult("background");
            stage.addChild(bg); //this where console gives red error in chrome
            //document.body.appendChild(bg); //this code works so imageurl is correct
            stage.update(); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

    <canvas id="demoCanvas", width="1000" height="700"></canvas>
</body>
```

The error message:
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new `Bitmap` and add that one to the stage:

```
        bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("background"));
        stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a double slash in your url:

`queue.loadFile({id:"background", src:"http://localhost//img/mainGameBG.png"});`

to

`queue.loadFile({id:"background", src:"http://localhost/img/mainGameBG.png"});`

Comment: ohh ya sorry, i just remove some part of the url when I posted here. Edited the post. I have the correct url on my original file.